# SLATEC rouitne dslucs() and MKL correspondence

Tags: conjugate-gradient, intel-mkl

I am looking for a routine (or set of routines) in the Intel MKL that that can replace `dslucs` (Incomplete LU BiConjugate Gradient Squared Ax=b Solver) in `SLATEC` (http://www.netlib.org/slatec/lin/).

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the MKL documentation, I see that MKL has only CG and GMRES solvers, along with ILU preconditioners.  It may be that the GMRES solver will be adequate for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use in site for more information perhaps this help you.
http://aam.mathematik.uni-freiburg.de/IAM/Research/projectskr/lin_solver/

Comment: This doesn't really address the question, which was specifically about routines in the MKL.